# How can I use boost::interprocess::private_node_allocator on a recursive datastructure?

Tags: boost, shared-memory, recursive-datastructures

I have a recursive datastructure I want to store in shared memory. Thus far I have got this (simplified):

```
using namespace boost::interprocess;
typedef allocator<wchar_t, 
managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>TCharAllocator;
typedef basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, TCharAllocator> MyShmString;


class Node;
template<>
struct sizeof_value<Node>
{
    static const std::size_t value = *NodeSize*; <---??
};


typedef private_node_allocator<Node, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager> TNodeAllocator;

class Node
{
  private:
    MyShmString _value;
    vector<Node, TNodeAllocator> _children;
};
```

If you fill in a number for Nodesize it compiles and runs. You can get this number by compiling and printing a sizeof(Node). This is not very robust. I have tried using a forward declared constexpr function returning the size of Node, but this does not compile (on MSVC).
Is there another way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the only source of complication is with declaring datastructures that entail incomplete types.

If the `boost::interprocess::sizeof_value<>` specialization works, that would be enough.¹

In terms of robustness, it is easy to add a `static_assert` after the definition of `Node` has become complete to ensure that the actual value matches the size reported by the compiler:

```
static_assert(boost::interprocess::sizeof_value<Node>::value == sizeof(Node), "sizeof mismatch");
```

---

¹ I have a hunch it can be done without that, but I cannot spend the time to make your code self-contained right now to check